# SQLite Query works in DB Browser but not in VSCode

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-code, browser

I have current VSCode and SQLite (alexcvzz) extension installed on Windows 11. Also have DB Browser installed. The following query works perfectly in DB Browser but not in VSCode. I opened DB in VSCode before attempting the query. Any thoughts as to why it's not working? Thanks for any suggestions (FYI, I'm a nooby with SQLite, VSCode and SQL - Please take that into consideration in your response!).

Query

INSERT INTO OwnerTable (UnitID,Owner,SaleDate,Price)
VALUES (10107,'Public, John Q','2022/03/19','280,000');

VSCode Error Message

[12:45:02 PM][vscode-sqlite][INFO] Activating extension vscode-sqlite v0.14.0...

[12:45:02 PM][vscode-sqlite][INFO] Extension activated.

[12:46:27 PM][vscode-sqlite][ERROR] Runtime error near line 4: unable to open database file (14)

PS: I've done numerous other queries in VSCode on same database and table and they have all worked without any issues.

Comment: Make sure that the database is not used by any other app.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks forpas. I checked out your suggestion just to make sure nothing else was using the data base. Nothing was. Then, I discovered the problem.

I use Windows Ransomware Protection. Thought it might be worthwhile to check it out to see if it was blocking the insert command. It was! It was then that I realized that all the other VSCode queries I had run were information retrieval queries, not queries that wrote to the database. All I had to do was "allow" the SQLite.exe file. That was the difference. Still don't know why it worked for DB Browser but not VSCode.